# Cannot take photo alert not redirecting to settings

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, uialertview

I am doing one application.In that i am trying to take the photo if space is not available.On that times i am getting the alert like "Cannot take photo" with two buttons Settings and Done.If i press the settings, it's not redirecting to settings page.And in last versions of OS,i am getting the same alert with only one OK button.So how to redirect to settings page in older versions.

Comment: show me the code what you have tried

Comment: My code is just to take the photo,os itself raising the alert.

Answer (score 0):

For redirecting Setting Page you can do Something like this:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

This will redirect to Setting page.

Hope it will be helpful

Comment: I getting the alert from the OS.I am creating the alert.